# WorkManager beginUniqueWork doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Currently, I'm using WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha02.

```
def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
// optional - Firebase JobDispatcher support
implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:$work_version"
```

I have no problem to execute background worker, by using the following code, when the app quit.

### Use enqueue, work as expected

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
        new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
                .addTag(SyncWorker.TAG)
                .build();

WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();

workManager.enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
```

---

Since, I would like to avoid more than one `SyncWorker` running at the same time. I try to use

### Use beginUniqueWork, doesn't work

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
        new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
                .addTag(SyncWorker.TAG)
                .build();

WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();

workManager.beginUniqueWork(
        SyncWorker.TAG,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        oneTimeWorkRequest
);
```

`SyncWorker` is not running at all.

May I know what step I had missed out? Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`beginUniqueWork()` returns a [`WorkContinuation` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation). You need to call `enqueue` on that `WorkContinuation` to actually enqueue it with WorkManager:

```
workManager.beginUniqueWork(
    SyncWorker.TAG,
    ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
    oneTimeWorkRequest
).enqueue();
```

Comment: Thanks. I manage to make it run now. I test using `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP`, and purposely make the worker doing infinity while loop with sleep. No more than 1 worker running. However, if I explicitly perform `cancelAllWorkByTag(SyncWorker.TAG)` and `cancelUniqueWork(SyncWorker.TAG)` before 2nd enqueue, I notice previous worker will not be killed. Yet, 2nd worker is allowed to run. This makes 2 workers running simultaneously. Does this mean, if we are using beginUniqueWork, we shouldn't call `cancelAllWorkByTag` and `cancelUniqueWork`?

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#cancelUniqueWork(java.lang.String)) cancelation is best effort. This applies equally for all types of Work

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Initially I thought if the cancel operation is not success, beginUniqueWork will not start another worker. Seem like my assumption is wrong.

Comment: There's additional [cancelation related APIs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79632247) that are to be added in alpha03. Your Worker would still need to check for cancellation though to end its work early if cancelled

Comment: Thanks. Do you know when will there be 1.0 version? As, we plan to release some code to production based on WorkManager. Would be nice to know when is the 1.0 be ready.

Comment: There's already a number of apps that have shipped WorkManager to production. Alpha for Architecture Components is more about API stability than runtime stability, but YMMV, test thoroughly, etc

Comment: By the way, to really ensure there's single Worker running, is using an additional synchronized a good way? - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/b165c483788b09830b3b28148ab7d4c0

Comment: Seems reasonable

Answer (score 13):

The answer from @ianhanniballake is of course helpful and correct, but I thought I'd point out that (with a fast-evolving API) there is a [new `enqueueUniqueWork()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueUniqueWork(java.lang.String,%2520androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy,%2520androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest)) so I guess the OP could now use:

```
workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
    SyncWorker.TAG,
    ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
    oneTimeWorkRequest
);
```

Comment: I have a similar code, however my Worker is not called, why would that be?