# WorkManager Unique Work is not being executed

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm using `WorkManager` version 1.0.1.

I'm creating the `WorkRequest` using this code:

```
 Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();
 Data data = new Data.Builder()
                                .putString(URL_KEY, url)
                                .putString(DATA_KEY, data)
                                .build();
 OneTimeWorkRequest sendWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SendWorker.class)
                                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                                        .setInputData(data)
                                        .addTag(SEND_WORK_TAG)
                                        .setBackoffCriteria(
                                                BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL,
                                                30,
                                                TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                        .build();
```

When I call `WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(sendWork)`, the work is being executed just fine, but I want to make sure that the execution is serial so I've tried to use

`WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork(SENDING_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, sendWork);`

or, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657520/workmanager-beginuniquework-doesnt-work-as-expected/50658120),

`WorkManager.getInstance().beginUniqueWork(SENDING_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, sendWork).enqueue();`

but the work is not being executed. Why?

P.S. also tried to add zero or very small `setInitialDelay` but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to create the work request without the constraints? do you have any log?

Comment: I tried without the constraints and without the backoff. No difference. Don't see anything unusual in the logs.

Comment: Please open a bug on the [WorkManager public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197) and possibly attach a sample project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please also try this on a stock Android device/emulator to see if it isn't a problem specific to your device.